# Recognize unicode symbol domains in text

Tags: php, regex, string, search, pcre

I have the following regex

```
(?!:\/\/)([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11}?$
```

which recognizes domains like **moo.foo** but it fails to recognize cases like:

- `festelån.net` having some unicode char
- `http://hellöthere.com/` or cases where the **http** or **https** protocol along with **slashes** are present.

How to modify it to recognize those cases?
I'm not good with regex appreciate your kind help.
Here's [online real time](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=109798) edit of the example if you want to play with it.

Comment: `(?!:\/\/)` is saying to not match the enclosed characters, meaning the `://` will not be part of the capture, [this alone should not break the regex](https://regex101.com/r/u7BuP1/1).  The reason the last example doesn't match (other than the unicode) is that the regex ending with `$` means that it must be at the end of the string, meaning the trailing `/` is preventing the match.  `[\p{L}\p{N}]` can be used in place of `[a-z0-9]` in order to match any unicode letter or number (`\p{L}` is any letter, `\p{N}` is any number)

Comment: 10x for the explanation  @SamRockett.  In your example this pattern `(?!:\/\/)([\p{L}\p{N}\-_]+\.)*[\p{L}\p{N}\][\p{L}\p{N}\-_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,11}}` catches what I am looking for but in php using `preg_match` it doesn't. Although it should still be `PCRE`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I have in my OpenSource project that might help you. I have used PHP [filtar_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function to apply the validation.

```
public function ValidateHost($Host)
    {
        if(isset($Host))
        {
            if(!is_null($Host) && !empty($Host))
            {
                if(strstr($Host, ".") && strlen($Host) > 3 && strlen($Host) < 255 && (!strstr($Host, "..")) && (!strstr($Host, " "))
                   && preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+/', $Host) && (!strstr($Host, "@")) &&
                   !(preg_match('/([^.]*[.][0-9]*$)/', $Host)) && filter_var(FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) == true)
                    return Config::RET_OK;
                else return Config::INVALID_HOST_NAME;
            }
            else return Config::INVALID_NULL;
        }
        else return Config::INVALID_NULL;
    }
```

In case you want to check out, here is my Project: [InfraTools](https://github.com/msiqueira-dev/InfraTools)

Comment: Would it be possible to explain what you're doing here and why it works? Just I'm seeing a lot of changes from the code in the question and I can't work out exactly why those changes were made, or how this would be able to solve the problem with unicode characters.

Comment: @SamRockett the function i have given is a generic function that validates a 
 given HostName. The Config::INVALID are constant, and could be replaced with return false and true. There are a couple of validations together, but the one more interesting for the cause if the post is FILTER_VALIDATE_URL. But during my old tests I have done these other validations together, that makes the function work as intended.